# Run an object of a Processing class

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I have a Processing class in Eclipse named: "VisualST" and I made an object called: "tree" of type VisualST. Now I understand you can run the class VisualST using the line below in the main function (which is in the class GUI).

`PApplet.main(new String[] {"VisualST" });`

The problem is that I am storing data into the VisualST class (hence the object) and I need a way to run that specific VisualST or just run a VisualST in which the fields can be edited when the program is running. When I just ran the PApplet main function I got the window to show but there was no way of accessing the fields that changed how the window was built.

I have it to edit fields upon a button click in the class GUI which is Java with no Processing imports:

```
 public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

        if(isInteger(BInput.getText())) 
            val = Integer.parseInt(BInput.getText());

         tree.setstval(val);//edits tree! a specific VisualST object
        }

    }
```

Here is the gist of the VisualST class:

```
    import processing.core.PApplet;

public class VisualST extends PApplet {

int stbranch;
int lvls;
//the branch class takes PApplet, length, value (that will be display), and rgb
public branch rt;
public int stval;//start value that should be changed when button is pressed


public void setup() {
    size(360, 640);
    stbranch = 120;
    lvls = 5;
}



public void draw() {
    background(150);
    //start at the top of screen and start drawing
    translate(width/2,0);
    //stval is passed through the constructor and then drawn as the value
    rt = new branch(this, stbranch, stval, 0, 0, 0);
    translate(0, stbranch);
    makeBranch(lvls, stbranch*2/3, 0);
}


void makeBranch(int lvls, double stlength, float y)
{
     //this makes the tree
}

        }
```

Here's the branch constructor:

```
    import processing.core.PApplet;

public class branch {


double y;
public int value;
PApplet parent;

int r;
int g;
int b;

private branch left;
private branch right;
int opacity; //0-255



branch(PApplet p, double fy, int v, int ir, int ig, int ib){
parent = p;
y = fy;
value = v;
opacity = 200;
parent.stroke(ir, ig, ib, opacity);
parent.line(0, 0, 0, (float)y);
parent.noFill();
parent.stroke(ir, ig, ib, opacity);
parent.ellipse(0, (float)(10+y), 20, 20); 
parent.fill(ir, ig, ib, opacity+25);
parent.text(value, -5,(float)(10+5+y));
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, why are you writing your own event handlers whne Processing has built in event handler code? Also, you can't "run a class", you can create an object and then call a method for that object, or you can call a static class method. I'd say reduce this code to a working minimal example without any fancy things to set color or sizes or anything, so we can see what you're trying to do. You might even discover what's going wrong while reducing your code to a minimal working example.

Comment: The problem is that I need to find a way to run that specific object of that class(tree)... wasn't trying to run a class. I also have event handlers because I have a non-Processing GUI along with the window, that I would like to be able to run, displaying the object tree.